# Simulation censored data in R

Tags: r, survival, simulation, censoring, interval-censoring

I am trying to simulate a data set of interval censored data(finite interval censored data, right censored data ,and left censored data). In fact, I created two monitoring times in R and I have the event times as follows:

```
 t=c(0.006718455,0.161062738,0.039317205, 1.191990037, 0.136097657, 
    0.356757675,0.130210118, 0.117245856, 0.221616497,  0.605064428)

 n=length(t)
  L=matrix(rep(0,n))
  R=matrix(rep(0,n))
```

I wrote the following code in R to create such kind of data set:

```
 c1=runif(n, 0.1,1)
 c2=c1+runif(n,0.1,1)

 for (i in 1:n){
  if (t[i]<=c1[i]) {L[i]=0
  R[i]=c1[i]}
 else if (c1[i]<t[i] && t[i]<=c2[i]) {L[i]=c1[i]
 R[i]=c2[i]
 }
 else if (t[i]>c2[i]) {L[i]=c2[i]
 R[i]=Inf
 }
```

I would like to have the same proportion of each of the above-mentioned censored data. What should I do in this regards?

Comment: It seems one } is missed. I got one right censored:            [,1]      [,2]
 [1,] 0.0000000 0.2606079
 [2,] 0.0000000 0.3568908
 [3,] 0.0000000 0.6665228
 [4,] 0.8247331       Inf
 [5,] 0.0000000 0.4993066
 [6,] 0.0000000 0.7571808
 [7,] 0.0000000 0.7013472
 [8,] 0.0000000 0.3804913
 [9,] 0.0000000 0.5307203
[10,] 0.3622691 0.7251276

Comment: "I would like to have the same proportion of each of the above-mentioned censored data." Two approach: 1) specify the distributions for survival time, right censoring time, left censoring time. Calculate the parameters such that the proportion of each kind of censoring is as you wanted. 2) As you did in your program, then try the different parameter, such as U(0.1,1) ==> U(0.1, 0.5), until you get what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

I tweaked your code a little, added a final `else` statement that may or may not be needed, and added a missing closing bracket. I just like to leave all possible options accounted for in my logical statements.

I also used `set.seed` to ensure the same results would be reproduced each time and I combined `t`, `c1` and `c2` so you could see them all together with `L` and `R`. Hopefully, this does what you are looking for.

```
t=c(0.006718455,0.161062738,0.039317205, 1.191990037, 0.136097657, 
    0.356757675,0.130210118, 0.117245856, 0.221616497,  0.605064428)

set.seed(543)

n=length(t)
L=matrix(rep(0,n))
R=matrix(rep(0,n))

c1=runif(n, 0.1,1)
c2=c1+runif(n,0.1,1)

cbind(L, R)

for (i in 1:n){
  if (t[i]<=c1[i]) {
    L[i]=0
    R[i]=c1[i]
    }
  else if (c1[i]<t[i] && t[i]<=c2[i]){
    L[i]=c1[i]
    R[i]=c2[i]
  }
  else if (t[i] >c2[i]){
    L[i]=c2[i]
    R[i]=Inf
  }
  else{
    L[i]=c1[i]
    R[i]=C2[i]
  }
}
cbind(L, R, t, c1, c2)
```

which produces:

```
                                    t        c1        c2
 [1,] 0.0000000 0.9205463 0.006718455 0.9205463 1.7214450
 [2,] 0.0000000 0.8326050 0.161062738 0.8326050 1.3255343
 [3,] 0.0000000 0.6162162 0.039317205 0.6162162 1.1024744
 [4,] 0.7801157       Inf 1.191990037 0.1929538 0.7801157
 [5,] 0.0000000 0.7002615 0.136097657 0.7002615 1.2487096
 [6,] 0.0000000 0.8928230 0.356757675 0.8928230 1.7881768
 [7,] 0.0000000 0.4819749 0.130210118 0.4819749 1.4383389
 [8,] 0.0000000 0.2878614 0.117245856 0.2878614 1.1879485
 [9,] 0.0000000 0.2490733 0.221616497 0.2490733 0.5793924
[10,] 0.3670763 0.7442843 0.605064428 0.3670763 0.7442843
```

EDIT (based on the comment below):

Try breaking up your distribution based on the median of `t`. This should get you something closer to what you expect in breaking things out in approximate thirds.

```
t=c(0.006718455,0.161062738,0.039317205, 1.191990037, 0.136097657, 
    0.356757675,0.130210118, 0.117245856, 0.221616497,  0.605064428)

set.seed(543)

n=length(t)
L=matrix(rep(0,n))
R=matrix(rep(0,n))

c1=runif(n, 0,median(t))
c2=c1+runif(n,0,median(t))

cbind(L, R)

for (i in 1:n){
  if (t[i]<=c1[i]) {
    L[i]=0
    R[i]=c1[i]
    }
  else if (c1[i]<t[i] && t[i]<=c2[i]){
    L[i]=c1[i]
    R[i]=c2[i]
  }
  else if (t[i] >c2[i]){
    L[i]=c2[i]
    R[i]=Inf
  }
  else{
    L[i]=c1[i]
    R[i]=C2[i]
  }
}
cbind(L, R, t, c1, c2)
```

which produces:

```
                                      t         c1         c2
 [1,] 0.00000000 0.13546326 0.006718455 0.13546326 0.25117400
 [2,] 0.12094510 0.18581346 0.161062738 0.12094510 0.18581346
 [3,] 0.00000000 0.08522167 0.039317205 0.08522167 0.14898870
 [4,] 0.09577079        Inf 1.191990037 0.01534565 0.09577079
 [5,] 0.09909664 0.17313053 0.136097657 0.09909664 0.17313053
 [6,] 0.26219069        Inf 0.356757675 0.13088644 0.26219069
 [7,] 0.06305990 0.20443627 0.130210118 0.06305990 0.20443627
 [8,] 0.03101387 0.16309954 0.117245856 0.03101387 0.16309954
 [9,] 0.06263356        Inf 0.221616497 0.02461038 0.06263356
[10,] 0.08985541        Inf 0.605064428 0.04409139 0.08985541
```

Since there is some randomness and this is a small sample you are not likely to get a perfect 1/3, 1/3, 1/3 distribution as you describe in the comment below. You get two left-censored scores, 4 right censored scores and 4 interval scores as you hoped for. Large samples should get closer to an even distribution as you hoped.

EDIT 2:

Okay so what if you decouple c1 and c2?

```
t=c(0.006718455,0.161062738,0.039317205, 1.191990037, 0.136097657, 
    0.356757675,0.130210118, 0.117245856, 0.221616497,  0.605064428)

set.seed(543)

n=length(t)
L=matrix(rep(0,n))
R=matrix(rep(0,n))

c1=runif(n, 0,quantile(t, 1/3))
c2=runif(n, quantile(t, 2/3), max(t))

cbind(L, R)

for (i in 1:n){
  if (t[i]<=c1[i]) {
    L[i]=0
    R[i]=c1[i]
    }
  else if (c1[i]<t[i] && t[i]<=c2[i]){
    L[i]=c1[i]
    R[i]=c2[i]
  }
  else{
    L[i]=c2[i]
    R[i]=Inf
  }
}
cbind(L, R, t, c1, c2)
```

Or alternatively you can add the randomness in as you go.

```
t=c(0.006718455,0.161062738,0.039317205, 1.191990037, 0.136097657, 
    0.356757675,0.130210118, 0.117245856, 0.221616497,  0.605064428)

set.seed(543)

n=length(t)
L=matrix(rep(0,n))
R=matrix(rep(0,n))

LB<-quantile(t, 1/3) 
UB<-quantile(t, 2/3)   

cbind(L, R)

for (i in 1:n){
  if (t[i]<=LB) {
    L[i]=0
    R[i]=runif(1, 0,quantile(t, 1/3))
    }
  else if (LB<t[i] && t[i]<=UB){
    L[i]=runif(1, 0,quantile(t, 1/3))
    R[i]=runif(1 ,quantile(t, 2/3), max(t))
  }
  else{
    L[i]=runif(1 ,quantile(t, 2/3), max(t))
    R[i]=Inf
  }
}
cbind(L, R, t)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but its not my desire. I want to have the same proportion(1/3) of finite interval-censored data, (1/3) of left-censored data and (1.3) of right-censored data. A s you can see, I have a great proportion of of left-censored data which is not my desire.

Comment: Okay. Now I understand a little better. 1/3 of your `L` & `R` matrix should be c1, c2. 1/3 should be 0, c1, and 1/3 should be c2, Inf

Comment: If that is the case, then I would say that the upper boundary for c1 is set too high for you not to find the statement `c1[i]<t[i]` to be true. You only have two values for `t` that are above the median of the uniform distribution specified for c1.

Comment: Yes. This is True.  How can I change the monitoring times to have the same proportion?

Comment: I updated my response to add one way of solving the program within the framework you originally proposed. This is undoubtedly not the only way to skin this cat.

Comment: Thanks, but for large sample, the proportion of right censored data is much and I have few finite interval-censored data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86832/discussion-between-matt-barstead-and-shany).